# Converting string to float in Java without round it

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounding in java Float.parseFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440833/rounding-in-java-float-parsefloat)

I want to convert strings to float i say:

```
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("1553781.9829"));
```

Output:

```
1553782.0
```

I say:

```
System.out.println(Float.valueOf("1553781.9829"));
```

Output:

```
1553782.0
```

How to get Float without lossing precision?

Comment: use `Double` instead of `Float`

Comment: Keep in mind that floating point values are approximate, not exact. `"1553781.9999999999"` would become `1553782`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1553781.9829"));` instead

float has a limitation of smaller size (4 bytes) so it's not good for big decimals, double has the double size (8 bytes)

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for **accuracy**, I would suggest **BigDecimal**

This is just like normal wrapper class which provides methods for all your operations. And yes  it takes argument as String as well.

```
  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1553781.9829");
  System.out.println(" bd :"+ bd);  //prints the same value
```

URL : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: if i will use BigDecimal i need to convert it in float later to work with it like with float type? I mean im already have classes works with float types i gonna remake it to work with BigDecimal?

Comment: You can perform all float operations with BigDecimal as well. So will suggest; replace float with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use float or double without a risk of losing precision. First of all their precision is limited, for float it is approx 7-8 decimal digits, for double ~16 digits. Apart from that Java floating points types are binary internally so they cannot store some decimal fractions without losing precision. If you really need exact decimal fractions use java.math.BigDecimal. Read "Effective Java" Item 48: "Avoid float and double if exact answers are required".

Comment: if i will use BigDecimal i need to convert it in float later to work with it like with float type? I mean im already have classes works with float types i gonna remake it to work with BigDecimal?

Comment: You can convert it to float or double when necessary as bd.floatValue() or db.doubleValue() if need be. But you also can work with it as BigDecimal, it has all necessary arithmetic.

Comment: But if ill convet bd in float i lose precision?

Comment: Yeah ill try convert db in float and it rounds. But thanks for answer)

Comment: Sure, it all depends, floats are short and fast, but you just need to be aware that accurracy is not gearanteed, even with doubles. See my update about "Effective Java"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Float` you can use `Double`

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf("1553781.9829"));
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1553781.9829"));
```